is it too cliche to foreshadow a character's future using their given names?
in the book i'm currently working on, i'm thinking of using unconventional names (sometimes even words that aren't names) that are heavily symbolic and supposed to predict what they future should be.
for example, one of the characters is named Camarilla (meaning: a group of unofficial often secret and scheming advisers). her character secretly manipulates who is essentially the "king" of the story. also, i like that it was the name of an exclusive vampire sect in Vampire: The Masquerade. however i wonder if its too cliche (i dont personally care about the lack of subtlety) or just plain weird to name her something like that.
there are some other names too, a lot of them, however i've derived from the words that are symbolic for said character. judging by the answers, i might do the same for Camarilla, though i've grown quite attached to it.
i do want to say that this does take place in a somewhat fantasy-like modern world. imagine fusion of corporate and like. mermaids, maybe. succession and supernatural, if you will. idk. main theme is that while the setting is corporate, the characters have "superpowers" or are a different species.

In your specific case, I've never heard the word "camarilla" before, and I dare to suggest that the vast majority of readers won't have heard of it either.

the names of characters in The Jungle Book are the words for the animals. Translated into English they are Black Panther the black panther, Bear the bear, Elephant the chief of the elephants, and his son Elephant Jr.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Jungle_Book_characters

F1Krazy, yess, i am aware of this. i just need to know if that would be a bad thing or not. i'm hoping it would be interesting for the readers that might on some level be aware of it, or atleast be interesting enough for few to look it up

As someone who has played Vampire: The Masquerade, it would put me out of the story to find a character called Camarilla. A bit like naming a bus driver Harry Potter. I think in my head I'd call her Carmilla so she has an actual woman's name (although it doesn't help that camarilla is a Spanish word, my native language, so for me it means "little chamber").

If you are going to write in English, you need to learn to start every sentence with a capital letter!!

I've never heard Camarilla, but wouldn't give it a second thought as a name. It sounds like a name, and that is the most important quality.
That said, I suspect a super-majority of readers, more than 75%, would not recognize this as foreshadowing in any sense.

"... i'm [sic] thinking of using unconventional names (sometimes even words that aren't names) that are heavily symbolic and supposed to predict what they [sic] future should be."

In general I think this is a bad mistake in writing.
While Camarilla sounds pretty "name-ish" and is acceptable, using words that are not "name-ish" (do not sound like names) is just making your story a hard trudge.
It will cause constant cognitive dissonance, and if anybody does catch on, if your foreshadowing is that spot on, you give away too much of the story.
For example, suppose you name your hero's best friend "Bedragare" (beh-DRAH-gah-reh). That is the Swedish word for "traitor, fraudster, or deceiver".
Well if any reader happens to know that, it is too "on the nose", it gives away the whole plot, the hero will be betrayed by her best friend.
On the other hand, "Bedra" (BAY-druh) might be okay, it is name-ish.
The more of this you do (like for all characters) the more likely it is somebody learns something about the characters that will ruin the story for them.
Not to mention the difficulty of stumbling through strange names, or the disappointment of readers finding out they have been pronouncing names wrong, etc.
Obviously you don't have to limit yourself to sixth grade English, but the more difficult you make your character names the less successful you will be.
Pick names that are common, or at least sound like names, and are easy to shorten to a single syllable or two.
Ben (+1) mentions "Katniss". This is a good use of a referential name; the katniss plant is aka the Arrowhead plant because its leaves look like arrowheads. But it doesn't give anything about the plot away; we are shown from the first scenes that Katniss is an expert archer. The symbolism here is hardly a blip, it isn't "foreshadowing" at all. "Everdeen" has no particular foreign meaning, but due to "ever" sounds reliable and consistent. It also foreshadows nothing.
To answer your question, yes, it is too cliche to foreshadow all your character's futures using their names, if their futures were not already fairly obvious from the start, Act I (hero or villain).
Finally, I worry you don't understand foreshadowing. It is not revealing the future. The key part here is "shadow", a shadow shows an outline of something, not an image of something. A foreshadowing event is something like the hero  failure to win a game of cards because Bob bluffed her, and then gloated about it.
Then later, a similar incident in which Bob is bluffing with much higher stakes, but the hero guesses Bob is bluffing and doesn't fall for it.
Effective foreshadowing fits into the narrative without revealing that it is foreshadowing; we only realize later that it was. In the case of Bob bluffing, it means nothing when it happens -- but for a reader that remembers it, reading the later incident when the stakes are higher, it can mean a lot -- they are thinking Bob is bluffing again!, and wondering if the hero will fall for it again. With a mental cheer when she doesn't.
Or perhaps the hero pretends to fall for Bob's bluff, fulfilling the foreshadowing, causing the reader despair, but secretly she has a backup plan -- a surprise for the reader, Yes! She really knew all along!
Foreshadowing is not "telling". Foreshadowing is an incident that sets up expectations or fears in the reader. Later, when something happens that is recognizably the same shape as the earlier incident, the reader has an expectation or fear it may work out the same way.

Some languages, like Turkish, have telling names, that is, names whose meaning the speakers of the language understand. Other languages, like English, have names whose meanings most speakers no longer comprehend. The average English speaker doesn't know that Sophia means "wisdom" or that John means "God has been gracious".
Because of this, speakers of English usually expect fictional names to be equally obscure. The average English speaking reader doesn't know what Frodo means or Katniss. Readers do accept telling names for characters from a culture where everyone has a telling name, such as in stories about Native Americans, but then most readers would expect that either all names are thus translated into English (Strong-as-an-Oak) or none (Cochise).
What those reader who notice it often find irritating, when the name of a character is only telling to the reader but not to the characters in the story themselves. For example, if you name a character Lupus (from Latin "wolf"), because his personality or physique are in some way wolf-like, but the Latin language doesn't exist in your fictional world or there are no wolves, then that may seem like you are trying to be clever.
I would consider your name Camarilla to fall into this latter category of awkward cleverness, unless there actually is such a group of courtiers in your world and it actually bears that name in your story, so that the name has the same meaning for both your readers and your characters.
